# Creating a dynamically polling graph in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

My plan is to create graphs that analyse data pulled a data simulator I have created.

The graphs requirements are:
Once the graph reaches 1 minute of data, it will auto scroll to the right
There will be a large number of graphs, so auto generating these would be key
[image: Model of what the graphs will look like]

Can anyone help with the above requirements? I understand how to make a simple graph, but do not know how to auto slide it after a set time, nor do I know how to auto generate different data from one section of code.

Any help is massively appreciated. Will edit the post with more information if it is asked of me.